# How do i play this tab? (guitar tab)

Tags: guitar, chords, electric-guitar

How do i play this? i know it's a chord but after the chords i'm not sure how to play it.

[image: tabs]

Comment: You play each note on each string on the given fret, in turn - every note gets played separately.

Answer (score 1):

It's an arpeggio, going up and down (frets 7 - 8 - 5 - 8) with the same basic position.

Basic position: index on string 6, ring finger on strings 3 and 2 (as in a barre):

Index on fret 7, ring finger on fret 7 (strings 3 and 2), then pick strings 6, 3, and 2

Index on fret 8, ring finger on fret 9 (strings 3 and 2), then pick strings 6, 3, and 2

Index on fret 5, ring finger on fret 5 (strings 3 and 2), then pick strings 6, 3, and 2

Index on fret 8, ring finger on fret 9 (strings 3 and 2), then pick strings 6, 3, and 2